# Why did Kingo say "Ignorance is bliss" in this scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021, eternals

In *Eternals* (2021), Karun and Kingo went to a forest where Druig resides:

> Karun: It's very nice here, sir.
>
> Kingo: Don't be fooled. **Ignorance is bliss**.

Why did Kingo say "Ignorance is bliss" in this scene?

Comment: Is it a normal forest? Because it sounds like it means the place is not nearly as friendly as it might be (i.e. there might be dangerous fauna and flora or such).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rest of the Eternals have just arrived at Druig's village. Here Druig is controlling the residents to remove violent and damaging impulses.

The Village is an idealised society, at the cost of free will. Accepting Ignorance in exchange for Bliss.

This is set up at the flashback to the site of Tenochtitlan.
[Transcript](https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/movies/eternals-2021-transcript/)

> We’ve trusted you for 7,000 years, and look where you’ve gotten us.
> I’ve watched humans destroy each other when I could stop it all in a heartbeat.
> Do you know what that does to someone after centuries?
> Could our mission have been a mistake?
> Are we really helping these people build a better world, huh?

> (DISTANT CLAMORING AND SCREAMING)
> We’re just like the soldiers down there.
> Pawns to their leaders.
> Blinded by loyalty.
> It ends now.

> (CLAMORING AND SCREAMING)
> (DRAMATIC MUSIC PLAYING)
> (SCREAMING AND CLAMORING SUBSIDE)
> Let them go.
> DRUIG: You’re gonna have to make me.
> Stop.
> DRUIG: If you wanna stop me, you’re gonna have to kill me.